# Using ESP32, TIP120s, and 12V DC to power three 12V solenoids

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator, dc, esp32, solenoid

I want to control three 12V solenoid valves with an ESP32, using the GPIO pins on the ESP to switch TIP120 MOSFETs.

The ESP would be powered by a separate USB supply.

I went to circuito.io and it suggested [this setup.](https://www.circuito.io/static/reply/index.html?solutionId=6474dd2d7425e4002e9cc8ee&solutionPath=storage.circuito.io)

What is the 5V regulator for? I don't want to connect the 12V to the ESP anyway.  Are the capacitors for smoothing? Are either of them absolutely necessary?

RE the MOSFETs I know that the gate voltage should be correlated to the power I want to send the the output. Is the 3.3V from the ESP GPIO going to be enough or too much? I tried to do the calculations myself but I'm not confident that I would have gotten it right. I don't want to blow the solenoids or the MOSFETs.

Comment: The [TIP120](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/tip120-d.pdf) is not a [MOSFET.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET)  The TIP120 is an [NPN Darlington transistor.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor)  A TIP120 will not work in a circuit intended for a MOSFET.

Comment: I was under the impression that the TIP120 could be used to switch a 12V supply on and off using a lower voltage signal. I saw a tutorial doing this with a 6V lamp and 3V from an ESP. Is this incorrect?

Comment: A TIP120 can be used to switch 12V, but it is not a MOSFET.  The rest of the circuit has to be designed to use the TIP120.  Even with a properly designed circuit, the TIP120 will get hotter than a MOSFET.  Use the components given in the circuit design rather than just whatever you have at hand.